# Azure Functions could not load libraries

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure Function to query a SQL Database, for that purpose I need to get an access token for which I create the following function

```
function accessToken($TenantId, $ClientId, $ServicePrincipalId, $ServicePrincipalPassword)
{
    $ResourceUrl = "https://database.windows.net/"
    $AuthorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId"
    $objClientCredentials = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]::new($ServicePrincipalId, $ServicePrincipalPassword)
    $objAuthenticationContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new($AuthorityUrl)
    $objAuthenticationResult = $objAuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync($ResourceUrl, $objClientCredentials)
    return $objAuthenticationResult.Result.AccessToken
}
```

When I run it on my machine it works, however when move it to an Azure Function it seems that the following are not loaded:

1. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential
2. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext

The following error is displayed:

> [Error] ERROR: Unable to find type
> [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential].Exception
> :Type        :
> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeExceptionErrorRecord :Exception
> :Type    :
> System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptionMessage
> : Unable to find type
> [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential].HResult
> : -2146233087

I have tried include them as follows:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext
```

but the error persist. Do you know what could be happening? Is there another way to load them on Azure Function?

Comment: What language you are using? Is it C#?

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure Portal, go the the function and enable MSI.  Try again.
More reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#obtain-tokens-for-azure-resources).

[image]